# Call returns Observable instead of actual object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, subscription

My call to `this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).then((user) => console.log(user));` keeps returning an Observable object instead of the actual data object - does anyone know how to fix it?

**DashboardComponent**

```
this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUserUid().then((uid) => {
  if (uid) {
    this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).then((user) => console.log(user));
  }
});
```

**DashboardFacade**

```
  getCurrentUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return this.userService.getUser(uid);
  }
```

**UserService**

```
  getUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then((token: string) => {
        this.logger.debug(`Token generated: ${token}`);
        return this.httpClient
          .get(`${environment.apiBasePath}/users`, {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          })
      });
  }
```

Trying to do:

```
this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUserUid().then(uid => {
  if(uid) {
    this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).subscribe(
     (user) => console.log(user)
    )
  }
});
```

throws the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(...).subscribe is not a function TypeError: this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(...).subscribe is not a function in DashboardComponent`

Comment: When you make a HTTP call, it returns you an observable. You can try to use observable <any>instead of promise< unknown >. See if that works and let me know..

Comment: so you can either convert that observable to promise or simply use as observable

Comment: Hover over then statement. Tell us it's return type. That's the problem.

Comment: I think the issue is in `getUser(uid: string)`, it returns a Promise instead of Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you have what we call Promise Chain. It happen when I promise return a Promise, the intermediate promise are kinda invisible and you receive the result of the last resolved promise of the chain.

your method **getUser** return a Promise, but this Promise actually don't return another promise but an Observable, in this case chain promise are not involved and you receive an Observable. What you can do it to transform your method to actually return a Promise if you don't need to observable :

```js
  getUser(uid: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then((token: string) => {
        this.logger.debug(`Token generated: ${token}`);
        return this.httpClient
          .get(`${environment.apiBasePath}/users`, {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          }).toPromise();                       <<<< transform to observable as promise
      });
  }
```

About your error this is also "normal"

```
this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUserUid().then(uid => {
  if(uid) {
    this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).subscribe(
     (user) => console.log(user)
    )
  }
});
```

**this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid)**  actually return a Promise (of Observable) not an Observable, so you need to wait the promise to be resolved before subscribing

could be something like this (if you keep observable in the getUser method)

```js
this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUserUid().then(uid => {
  if(uid) {
    this.dashboardFacade.getCurrentUser(uid).then(currentUserOsb => {
        currentUserObs.subscribe(user => console.log(user));
    });
  }
});
```